# Proving two group-homorphism coincide over certain conditions

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I'm given two groups, say $G$ and $H$, and two homomorphism, say $f$ and $g$ both from $G$ to $H$. Define $A=\{ x\in G | f(x)=g(x)\}$, I've managed to prove that $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ and that if $H$ is abelian $A$ is also normal then I'm stucked in proving that if $G=\ker (f) A$ then $f$ coincides with $g$ (it is not specified if this happens when $H$ is abelian so I don't know if I have to suppose that from the first point that I've mentioned).

Done that I have to work in the case in which $G$ has order $36$ while $H$ has order $3$ (so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3$) and $9$ divides the order of $A$ to conclude again that $f$ and $g$ must coincide. In this case $H$ is abelian so I was thinking to prove that $G/A$ is isomorphic to $\ker f$ but I don't know how to proceed any further (and if it is the right way in the first place).

Comment: By $\ker(f)A$ do you mean $\{ga \in G : g \in \ker(f) \text{ and } a \in A\}$?

Comment: @A.P. it is not specified in the exercise so I guessed the same

Comment: Can you tell us where the exercise came from, then?

Comment: @A.P. My algebra 2 teacher's website (which is in Italian)

Comment: Claim is false. Take $G=H=C_2\times C_2$, with $C_2=\{1,x\}$. Let $f,g\colon G\to H$ given by $f(a,b) = (1,b)$ and $g(a,b)=(a,b)$. Then $A=\{(1,1), (1,x)\}$ and $\mathrm{ker}(f) = \{(1,1), (x,1)\}$. In particular, $\mathrm{ker}(f)A=G$, but $f\neq g$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I've come to similar considerations but since the text said so I thought I was wrong, however in the more concrete case I mention in the second part of my question does perhaps the claim works ?

Answer (score 4):

The conditions given in the first paragraph are not enough, even if we assume that neither $\mathrm{ker}(f)$ nor $A$ are the the whole group (or nontrivial); let $G=H=C_2\times C_2$, with $C_2$ generated by $x$ and written multiplicatively. Let $f,g\colon G\to H$ be given by $f(a,b) = (1,b)$, and $g(a,b)=(a,b)$. Then $A=\{(1,1), (1,x)\}$, and $\mathrm{ker}(f) = \{(1,1),(x,1)\}$; therefore, $\mathrm{ker}(f)A=G$, but $f\neq g$.

In the specific case that $H\cong C_3$, $|G|=36$, and it is known that $9\bigm||A|$, the situation is pretty easy.

Note that any $2$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ must be in the kernel of any homomorphism from $G$ to $C_3$; in particular, both $f$ and $g$ must agree on all $2$-Sylow subgroups of $G$. Thus, $A$ contains a subgroup of order $4$. Since we also know that the order of $A$ is a multiple of $9$, it follows that the order of $A$ must be $36$; that is, $A=G$, so $f=g$.